# Ping-pong game with JavaScript and Canvas

Tags: javascript, performance, game, collision, canvas

I have created my first ping-pong game with JavaScript and Canvas. I will be glad if anybody can tell me how to optimize the code and functionality.

https://github.com/nikitalarionov/js-pong

First collision detection:

```
//Function to check collision between ball and one of
//the paddles
function collides(b, p) {

    if(b.x + ball.r >= p.x + p.w && b.x - ball.r <= p.x + p.w) {

        if (b.y + b.r >= p.y && b.y + b.r <= p.y + p.h && b.x - b.r <= p.x) {
            paddleHit = 1;
            if(b.x < W/ 2) {
                hit++;
            } else if (b.x > W / 2) {
                hit2++;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if(b.y - b.r <= p.y && b.y - b.r >= p.y - p.h && b.x + b.r >= p.x) {
            paddleHit = 2;
            if(b.x < W/ 2) {
                hit++;
            } else if (b.x > W / 2) {
                hit2++;
            }                
            return true;
        }
        else return false;

    }
}
```

I experience bad performance when the ball hits an angle of one of the paddles:

```
// Function that updates everything, score, positions, main game logic
function update(){
    // Move the padles
    for(var i = 0; i <= padles.length; i++) {
        var p = padles[i];
        if (i === 0 && players[0].moveUp) {
            if (p.y <= 0) {
                p.y = 0;
            }
            else {
                                    // is it how i move left paddle
                                    // it is doesn't work good like a mousemove
                                    // animations is slowly, i dont know how to fix it
                p.y -=25;    
            }
        }
        if (i === 0 && players[0].moveDown) {
            if (p.y + p.h >= H) {
                p.y = H - p.h;
            }
            else {
                p.y += 25;
            }
        }
        if (mouse.y && i === 1) {
            if (p.y + p.h >= H && mouse.y > p.y) {
                p.y = H - p.h;
            }
            else {
                p.y = (mouse.y -50) - p.w / 10;    
            }
        }
    }

            // ... some code

}
```

There I have very lazy animation and moving of the left paddle. I use keys for it outside of the animation cycle:

```
    // Add Global Event to handle keyboards buttons
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 87) {
        players[0].moveUp = true;
    } else
    if (e.keyCode === 83) {
        players[0].moveDown = true;
    }
}, false);

window.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 87) {
        players[0].moveUp = false;
    } else
    if (e.keyCode === 83) {
        players[0].moveDown = false;
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: I posted some code with problems, but it works, but not good :) It seems i have two problem (Collision Detection, Lazy Moving of left paddle).

Comment: this code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/9vgq6/ for the lazy among us :)

Answer (score 6):

From a once-over,

- Short 1 letter variables are terrible ( except for `x` and `y` ), `b`, `p` and `W` are just terrible
- Also please spellcheck your variables: `padles` -> `paddles`
- You should only detect collision when the ball is going to the left and gets in the danger-zone or when it is going to the right and getting in the danger-zone. So instead of doing 8 accesses, 1 AND and 4 sums (`if(b.x + ball.r >= p.x + p.w && b.x - ball.r <= p.x + p.w) {`) you should rather do something like

  ```
  if( deltaX < 0 && ball.x < someLimit ){
    testCollision( ball , leftPaddle );
  } else if( ball.x > someOtherLimit  ) {
    testCollision( ball , rightPaddle );
  }
  ```

  Where deltaX is the amount of pixels the ball is moving over the X axis, this should make paddle collision a lot more efficient
- Please don't use magical constants, in this case I see `25` all over the place
- Same for the keycodes, you should use constants for those

Comment: Remember that there aren't any *real* constants in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

1. The source of the slowness is due to the interaction with the
       `collision` object, I think.
2. There is also a flaw with your collision management as the ball can
   noclip out of the canvas.

   In pseudocode, you handle object position and speed like this (one
   dimensional simplification) :

   ```
   x += v;
   if (collides) {v = -v;}
   ```

   With this approach, if the objects speed is great enough then the
   object can get past the barrier and it will noclip. Instead, you
   want your code to look like this:

   ```
   if (x += v leads to collision) {
       v = -v;
   }
   else {
       x += v;
   }
   ```

   or some variation thereof.
3. Paddle movement feels fine to me.
4. Whatever this 'particles' thing is, doesn't seem to work.